# Diferença entre dois Arrays Multidimensionais com PHP

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Tenho estes dois arrays multidimensionais e gostaria da diferença entre eles, semelhante ao que a função `array_diff` faz, porém com arrays multidimensionais:

`$array_1:`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idAmbiente] => 1
            [nomeAmbiente] => Desenvolvimento
            [codAmbiente] => D
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idAmbiente] => 2
            [nomeAmbiente] => Produção
            [codAmbiente] => P
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [idAmbiente] => 3
            [nomeAmbiente] => Testes
            [codAmbiente] => T
        ) 
)
```

`$array_2:`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idVisibilidade] => 14
            [urlSistema] => http://www-gexdia/prevsuporte
            [responsavelVisibilidade] => 12
            [sistema_idSistema] => 10
            [idAmbiente] => 2
            [dataBaseList] => 18
        ) 
)
```

Gostaria que a função fizesse algo do tipo: `array_diff_multidimensional($array_1,$array_2,'idAmbiente');`

Resultado:

```
Array
( 
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idAmbiente] => 1
            [nomeAmbiente] => Desenvolvimento
            [codAmbiente] => D
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idAmbiente] => 3
            [nomeAmbiente] => Testes
            [codAmbiente] => T
        ) 
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiz duas funcoes, `array_enkeyize` para transformar o valor de um item em key das arrays e `array_dekeyize` para traformar a key em um valor de um item declarado nos parametros

```
function array_enkeyize($array, $iten) {
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $v_key => $v_value) {
        if ($v_key === $iten){
            $keized[$v_value] = $array[$key];
            unset($keized[$v_value][$iten]);
        }     
    }
  }

  return $keized;
}


function array_dekeyize($array, $iten) {
    $i = 0;
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {      
    $dekeized[$i] = $array[$key];
    $dekeized[$i++][$iten] = $key; 
  }

  return $dekeized;
}
```

#### Como usar

```
$array1 = array_enkeyize($array_1, 'idAmbiente');
$array2 = array_enkeyize($array_2, 'idAmbiente');

$result = array_diff_key($array1, $array2);

$result = array_dekeyize($result, 'idAmbiente');

var_dump($result);
```

#### Resultado

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'nomeAmbiente' => string 'Desenvolvimento' (length=15)
      'codAmbiente' => string 'D' (length=1)
      'idAmbiente' => int 1
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'nomeAmbiente' => string 'Testes' (length=6)
      'codAmbiente' => string 'T' (length=1)
      'idAmbiente' => int 3
```

=)

Answer (score 2):

Como a chave é relevante para a comparação entre os arrays (idAmbiente), o que você procura é algo mais próximo de um [`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

Como seus arrays são multidimensionais, será preciso uma função recursiva para percorrer e comparar os arrays internos. Nos comentários da própria documentação do php temos a implementação da [função recursiva](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff-assoc.php#73972) que você precisa:

```
<?php
function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2)
{
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
              if(!isset($array2[$key]))
              {
                  $difference[$key] = $value;
              }
              elseif(!is_array($array2[$key]))
              {
                  $difference[$key] = $value;
              }
              else
              {
                  $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                  if($new_diff != FALSE)
                  {
                        $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
                  }
              }
          }
          elseif(!isset($array2[$key]) || $array2[$key] != $value)
          {
              $difference[$key] = $value;
          }
    }
    return !isset($difference) ? 0 : $difference;
}
```

---

Como essa função utiliza `isset`, caso seu array possua uma chave com `null`, o resultado pode não ser o esperado, pois o `isset` retornará a posição em `null` mesmo que elas casem entre os arrays:

```
<?php

$array1 = array('a' => null, 'b' => null);
$array2 = array('a' => null);

var_dump(array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2));
```

Retorna:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    NULL
    ["b"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Para contornar essa situação, nos comentários da mesma função, temos uma [implementação que substitui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff-assoc.php#111675) o `isset` por `array_key_exists`.

Recomendo o uso da implementação com `array_key_exists` somente se você **precisa** de verdade da diferença entre chaves nulas. Funções recursivas são [mais lentas por natureza](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_%28ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29#Recurs.C3.A3o_versus_Itera.C3.A7.C3.A3o), e como o `isset` é mais rápido que `array_key_exists` por ser um construtor de linguagem e não uma função, em casos de arrays gigantes o `isset` irá apresentar um desempenho melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de contornar esse problema é usar a função, nativa do PHP, array_udiff mais uma função de callback. É importante, na comparação, que os tipos de dados sejam os mesmo. Segue o exemplo:

```
// DIFERENÇA ENTRE ARRAYS
$arrayA = [
  'rotas' => [
    'rota' => 'rota1',
    'ver'  => 1,
    'mod'  => 1
  ],
  [
    'rota' => 'rota2',
    'ver'  => 1,
    'mod'  => 1
  ]
];

$arrayB = [
  'rotas' => [
    'rota' => 'rota1',
    'ver'  => 1,
    'mod'  => 1
  ],
  [
    'rota' => 'rota2',
    'ver'  => 1,
    'mod'  => 0
  ]
];

// MOSTRA OS VALORES DE $arrayA QUE NÃO ESTÃO EM $arrayB
$result = array_udiff($arrayA, $arrayB, 'udiffCompare');

// DEBUG OSEIAS
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';

// FUNÇÃO PARA COMPARAR OS ELEMENTOS DO ARRAY
function udiffCompare($a, $b)
{
  $a = serialize($a);
  $b = serialize($b);
  return $a <=> $b;
}
```

Manual do PHP
[Função array_udiff](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-udiff.php)
[Função serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).